# Strategies for packing data into OpenGL 3D array

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, textures, octree

I am implementing a voxel raycaster in OpenGL 4.3.0. I have got a basic version going where I store a 256x256x256 voxel data set of float values in a 3D texture of the same dimensions.

However, I want to make a LOD scheme using an octree. I have the data stored in a 1D array on the host side. The root has index 0, the root's children have indices 1-8, the next level have indices 9-72 and so on. The octree has 9 levels in total (where the last level has the full 256x256x256 resolution). Since the octree will always be full the structure is implicit and there is no need to store pointers, just the one float value per voxel. I have the 1D indexing and traversal algorithms all set.

My problem is that I don't know how to store this in a texture. GL_TEXTURE_MAX_SIZE is way too small (16384) for using the 1D array approach for which I have figured out the indexing. I need to store this in a 3D texture, and I don't know what will happen when I try to cram my 1D array in there, nor do I know how to choose a size and a 1D->3D conversion scheme to not waste space or time.

My question is if someone has a good strategy for storing this whole octree structure in one 3D texture, and in that case how to choose dimensions and indexing for it.

Comment: You max texture size is not 3397, but the enum value of the property. Use the following code to get the max texture dimensions:

    int size;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &size);

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing this out! I have edited the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some words on porting your 1D-array solution directly:

First of all, as *Mortennobel* says in his comment, the max texture size is very likely *not* `3397`, that's just the enum value of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` (how should the *opengl.h* Header, that defines this value, know your hardware and driver limits?). To get the actual value from your implementation use `int size; glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &size);`. But even then this might be too small for you (maybe 8192 or something similar).

But to get much larger 1D arrays into your shaders, you can use [buffer textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) (which are core since OpenGL 3, and therefore present on DX10 class hardware). Those are textures sourcing their data from standard OpenGL buffer objects. But those textures are always 1D, accessed by integer texCoords (array indices, so to say) and not filtered. So they are effectively not really textures, but a way to access a buffer object as a linear 1D array inside a shader, which is a perfect fit for your needs (and in fact a much better fit than a normal filtered and normalized 1D texture).

---

**EDIT:** You might also think about using a straight-forward 3D texture like you did before, but with homemade mipmap levels (yes, a 3D texture can have mipmaps, too) for the higher parts of the hierarchy. So mipmap level 0 is the fine 256 grid, level 1 contains the coarser 128 grid, ... But to work with this data structure effectively, you will probably need explicit LOD texture access in the shader (using `textureLod` or, even better without filtering, `texelFetch`), which requires OpenGL 3, too.

---

**EDIT:** If you don't have support for OpenGL 3, I would still not suggest to use 3D textures to put your 1D array into, but rather 2D textures, like *Rahul* suggests in his answer (the 1D-2D index magic isn't really that hard). But if you have OpenGL 3, then I would either use buffer textures for using your linear 1D array layout directly, or a 3D texture with mipmaps for a straight-forward octree mapping (or maybe come up with a completely different and more sophisticated data structure for the voxel grid in the first place).

---

**EDIT:** Of course a fully subdivided octree is not really using the memory saving features of octrees to its advantage. For a more dynamic and memory efficient method of packing octrees into 3D textures, you might also take some inspiration from this classic [GPU Gems article on octree textures](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter37.html). They basically store all octree cells as 2x2x2 grids arbitrarily into a 3D texture using the interal nodes' values as pointers to the children in this texture. Of course nowadays you can employ all sorts of refinements on this (since it seems you want the internal nodes to store data, too), like storing integers alongside floats and using nice bit encodings and the like, but the basic idea is pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, I will try buffer textures for sure. I do have support for OpenGL 3. I will start there, at least! The longer term goal is to be able to use a sparse octree, but the full octree will be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution sketch/outline:

Use a 2D texture to store your 256x256x256 (it'll be 4096x4096 -- I hope you're using an OpenGL platform that supports 4k x 4k textures).

Now store your 1D data in row-major order. Inside your raycaster, simply do a row/col conversion (from 1D address to 4k x 4k) and look up the value you need.

I trust that you will figure out the rest yourself :)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was not to pack a 256x256x256 dataset into a texture. That part was the one I had figured out!